# Creating a simple radio buttons form with greyed-out buttons

Tags: html, css

In the following code:

```
<form>
     <input type="radio" style="disabled:true">Alpha<br>
     <input type="radio" style="enabled:false">Beta<br>
     <input type="radio">Gamma<br>
</form>
```

1) Why is it allowing me to select more than one radio button at a time?

2) How to I "grey out" specific radio buttons? The "enabled" and "disabled" attributes do not seem to be working.

Comment: Further to what the others have all said, if you wrap the radio-button with a label tag, you can select the button by pressing on the text too - much easier than a fiddly little circle. I.e `<label><input type='radio' name='yourGroup' disabled/>Beta</label><br>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a group of radio buttons, give them all the same name:

```
<form>
     <input type="radio" name="group1">Alpha<br>
     <input type="radio" name="group1">Beta<br>
     <input type="radio" name="group1">Gamma<br>
</form>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/n9gM7/)
To disable a radio button, use the disabled attribute in its tag:

```
<form>
         <input type="radio" name="group1">Alpha<br>
         <input type="radio" name="group1">Beta<br>
         <input type="radio" name="group1" disabled>Gamma<br>
    </form>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/m4LY4/)
Disabled is not a CSS attribute so it is not defined within the style attribute.
As commented above you can also wrap the `<input>` in a `<label>` tag like so:

```
<form>
             <label><input type="radio" name="group1">Alpha</label><br>
             <label><input type="radio" name="group1">Beta</label><br>
             <label><input type="radio" name="group1" disabled></label>Gamma<br>
        </form>
```

Or you can link the label with the inputs id:

```
<label for="alpha">Alpha</label>
 <input type="radio" name="group1" id="alpha">
```

Then the user can click on the text instead of just the radio button.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/mRY7d/)

Answer (score 1):

The disabled attribute isn't a css style. You disable an input like this:

```
<form>
     <input type="radio" name="radGroup">Alpha<br>
     <input type="radio" name="radGroup" disabled>Beta<br>
     <input type="radio" name="radGroup">Gamma<br>
</form>
```

notice also the `name` attribute. This will prevent multple radio buttons been selected at once. Each input in the group must share the same `name`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3AMXP/)

Answer (score 1):

1. a group of radiobuttons must have the same same to select only one:
2. use the html `disabled` attribute to disable a radio `<input type="radio" disabled>`

so your solution would be:

```
<form>
     <input type="radio" name="rb1">Alpha<br>
     <input type="radio" name="rb1">Beta<br>
     <input type="radio" name="rb1" disabled>Gamma<br>
</form>
```